# C++ error trying to 'rewrite' char array

Tags: c++, string, pointers, toupper

I am trying to convert a string into all upper case using the code:

```
int client::get_upper(char*item_in)
{
    int k ;
    char * temp_str;
    int length = strlen(item_in);
    temp_str = new char [length+1];
    for(k = 0; k < length; ++k)
        temp_str[k] = toupper(item_in[k]);
    temp_str[k] = '\0';
    for(k = 0; k < length; ++k)
        item_in[k] = temp_str[k];
    return 0;
}
```

Yet when I attempt to do so I receive an access violation writing location xxxxxxxx from Visual Studio.  This is for a class, so I am restricted from using actual strings.

Comment: Show us how you *call* this function.

Comment: Any reason why you are allocating a second char array, rather than just writing the upper-case letters into the original array directly?  (btw you are leaking memory because you never do a delete [] temp_str at the end of the function)

Comment: Lord save us from "C with classes" teachers!

Comment: @JerryCoffin Indeed, but it seems to me they're here to stay (judging from my country's school system). Only way is for the Lord to kill them with fire. Or at least, introduce them to C++, the accompanying standard library and this thing they call the string class.

Comment: @DomagojPandža: I can even understand wanting to teach low-level programming, but if that's your intent, start by *implementing* a (minimal) string class, then use it (or extend it) for later lessons.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works if used properly (simplest way is to simply pass a local cstring like this):

```
char test[] = "stackoverflow.com";
client::get_upper(test); // client interpreted as a namespace
```

Now, your function is full of bad approaches, namely the redundant copy which is left unmanaged ( a memory leak).

Rewritten a bit:

```
int client::get_upper(char *item_in)
{
    unsigned int length = strlen(item_in);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++k)
        item_in[i] = toupper(item_in[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to experiment a bit, here something for you, just for fun:

```
int client::get_upper(char *item_in)
{
    int length = strlen(item_in);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        if((item_in[i] >= 97 && item_in[i] <= 122))
            item_in[i] = (int)item_in[i] - 32; 

    return 0;
}
```

And your error most likely comes from the fact that you're trying to push a dynamic array of characters which you probably didn't really think through. Simply use a local character string, a simple null-terminated array. You didn't really give as a lot to go on, so this is just guess work. All I can do is help you simplify your expression. Since the return value does nothing, consider applying it to something or switch to `void`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: For whatever reason I just assumed x = toupper(x) wouldnt work, probably sure to a lack of understanding on my part as to what actually happens when I do that.

Comment: Works great now though, switched from studio to good old notepad and g++ and that cleared up a lot of issues in and of itself.  I'm sure a lot of the code is crap, but there's a lot we dont learn about the language in this class it seems...  The function is just being used to take a users input and generate the correct hash key, I figured uniform case would be easiest.

Comment: And the int return is just recommended for good habit so we can make use of how/where a function exits...  I guess?

Comment: @user1404053 Usually returning an integer value in this context is just used to validate if things went according to plan. You can define 1 to be success and 0 to be failure. There can be more complex usage cases, it just depends on your project.

Comment: Yeah, the instructor just had us get in the habit of doing int instead of void.  99% of the time it's nothing more than a success/fail flag that I dont even implement.  But, every so often it can tell the client which table was empty or how many items were found and inserted into the client list.  I'm sure there are a myriad of other ways of doing the things we do with C/C++, but I get the feeling the object is to have us take as many steps as possible.

Comment: @user1404053 Don't worry about it, just take your time, learn and improve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you call that code correctly, I think you have an off-by-one error with temp_str[k] = '\0';

Comment: K is equal to the kength, and he allocated length + 1, so it's O.K

Comment: Well, it's still pointless, because he copies it all back into the original array, it's not /wrong/, but it's weird, just the same.

Answer (score 0):

When calling get_upper, did you pass a string literal? For example, is your calling code something like this:

```
char *mystr = "stackoverflow.com";
client.get_upper(mystr)?
```

That will most likely trigger an access violation in Visual Studio.

If this is the case, you can change the definition of mystr to:

```
char mystr[] = "stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t(v=vs.80).aspx
"The result of modifying a string constant is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell why you are getting an error without seeing how the function is being called.

My suspicion is that the error has to do with the calling context and what item_in is actually pointing to.

Jeremy Friesner's comments are spot-on - you have a leak and you don't need the intermediate buffer anyway if the goal is for this to be destructive.

Answer (score 0):

The mere fact that you're not allowed to use the standard string class doesn't mean you have to write this as a monolithic function.

I'd write a simple function to do the transformation in-place. Then, if you need to support working on read-only strings, write another function that duplicates input (using yet a third function) and then does an in-place transformation on the duplicate.

```
char *duplicate(char const *input);

char *upper_str(char *input); // does in-place transformation

char *upper_str(char const *input); // duplicates, then transforms the duplicate
```